# Sales list force change of column in lines

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, erp, navision, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2016

I'm using the page below a POS sales list. Here the user can use the barcode pistol and pass the article and the code is translated into the item no.
The problem is when they use the pistol and end to pick a item and want to pass to next one the line go automatically to the first column (Item type) and my goal was to force to go into the second column (Item no), because the Item type is by default the type "product".

Only change the order of columns of Item no to Item product is not enough in this case.
[image]

Comment: If you are adding only product lines, why you dont force the new lines to have te type product and then you move the field to other position after the No. or simply you can hide the field.

Comment: because with that when the pistol finish picking the item, it goes to the description field

Comment: More simple then. Why you dont change the end string to fill with a down arrow, and then you move to the next line No.?

Comment: I didn't understand sorry, can you explain better?

Comment: In barcode readers normally you can configure on the driver the end of text character. Why dont you configure down arrow to jump to next line "No.".

Comment: Ok I will see that, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `ACTIVATE` is not supported for controls in RTC.
Not many good options here.

- Try using [QuickEntry Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsnav-2016/hh166926(v=nav.90)). Set it to `false` for all controls on subpage except `No.`.
- Create custom page with as less fields as possible, use it as buffer to scan all items and create sales lines upon closing of this new page. You can implement desired behavior on this page and keep original page almost unmodified
- Create add-in that will intercept scanner output somehow.

Comment: So only put QucikEntry to in the "no." field.. i did that but when I use the pistol it goes two lines under

Comment: Most probably scanner sends carriage return or tab symbols st the end of the barcode sequence. Try scanning into notepad to see symbols and reprogram your scanner accordingly.